# Сбой в phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Использую ubuntu 16, phpmyadmin после некоторого времени работы стал выводить панель в таком виде. Подскажите как исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `ctrl+f5` обновить стили ?

Answer (score 0):

Попробовать перезагрузить через ctrl-f5, если не помогает, то переустановить, вполне возможно обновился криво

Comment: Не получилось ни с помощью ctrl+f5 ни с переустановкой